# I cannot install updates and software in 16.04

Tags: software-installation, updates

I am not able to update the system and install software in Ubuntu 16.04.

```
sreejithkm@sreejithkm-Inspiron-3537:~$ sudo apt-get updates
E: Invalid operation updates
sreejithkm@sreejithkm-Inspiron-3537:~$
```

What am I doing wrong, what do I have to do?

Comment: Where did you get this command?

Answer (score 3):

You just use the wrong command, the correct command is : `sudo apt-get update` Let's test it ...

```
$ sudo apt-get updates
E: Invalid operation updates
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

Note : This is an example from the setup on Ubuntu 16.10, repositories are different in your case.